# Primitive Calculator - Dynamic Approach

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm having some trouble getting the correct solution for the following problem:

> Your goal is given a positive integer n, find the minimum number of
>   operations needed to obtain the number n starting from the number 1.

More specifically the test case I have in the comments below.

```
 # Failed case #3/16: (Wrong answer)
    # got: 15 expected: 14
    # Input:
    # 96234
    #
    # Your output:
    # 15
    # 1 2 4 5 10 11 22 66 198 594 1782 5346 16038 16039 32078 96234
    # Correct output:
    # 14
    # 1 3 9 10 11 22 66 198 594 1782 5346 16038 16039 32078 96234
    #  (Time used: 0.10/5.50, memory used: 8601600/134217728.)


    def optimal_sequence(n):
        sequence = []

        while n >= 1:
            sequence.append(n)

            if n % 3 == 0:
                n = n // 3
                optimal_sequence(n)

            elif n % 2 == 0:
               n = n // 2
               optimal_sequence(n)

            else:
               n = n - 1
               optimal_sequence(n)

        return reversed(sequence)

    input = sys.stdin.read()
    n = int(input)
    sequence = list(optimal_sequence(n))
    print(len(sequence) - 1)
    for x in sequence:
        print(x, end=' ')
```

It looks like I should be outputting 9 where I'm outputting 4 & 5 but I'm not sure why this isn't the case. What's the best way to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Your code is finding the *first* path (`10 % 2 == 0`), not the *shortest*. You need to add some search logic to it.

Comment: _"I should be outputting 9 where I'm outputting 4 & 5"_ More to the point, you are outputting `2 4 5` when you should be outputting `3 9`. What operations are you allowed?

Comment: @TedHopp you can see them in the code: divide by two; divide by three; or subtract one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe additional conditional logic or something within that path that outputs what I need?

Comment: Additional logic; wherever more than one operation is valid you need to try all of them and return the one that resulted in the shortest valid path. Look into memoization too, that will speed up the process.

Comment: @jonrsharpe okay so at a high level I need to have conditional logic to determine which operation is more preferred in this case and store it accordingly. Then use the preferred operations I stored in my base logic?

Comment: Wait, does your code even work at all? The first three lines of `optimal_sequence` would just return an empty list every time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i may of had that first if statement commented out locally. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic programming for primitive calculator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930086/dynamic-programming-for-primitive-calculator)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are doing a greedy approach.
When n == 10, you check and see if it's divisible by 2 assuming that's the best step, which is wrong in this case.

What you need to do is proper dynamic programming. `v[x]` will hold the minimum number of steps to get to result `x`.

```
def solve(n):
  v = [0]*(n+1)  # so that v[n] is there
  v[1] = 1  # length of the sequence to 1 is 1
  for i in range(1,n):
    if not v[i]: continue
    if v[i+1] == 0 or v[i+1] > v[i] + 1: v[i+1] = v[i] + 1
    # Similar for i*2 and i*3
  
  solution = []
  while n > 1:
    solution.append(n)
    if v[n-1] == v[n] - 1: n = n-1
    if n%2 == 0 and v[n//2] == v[n] -1: n = n//2
    # Likewise for n//3
  solution.append(1)
  return reverse(solution)
```

Comment: So it seems I'm having a hard time grasping how the minimum number of steps is determined in this case. Looks like the list gets updated in the event that the i-th plus one element is equal to 0 or greater than the i-th, but I'm just not seeing at first glance the significance of this.

Comment: Take 10 as an example. when i = 5, v[i]= 4 so via the i*2 branch you are going to write 5 to v[10]. As you progress you will reach i=9 with v[9] = 3. so now you want to update v[10] which is no longer 0 with 4. Since 5 > 4 you will write there 4. In short the condition says update a position if this is the first time you get there (v[i+1] == 0) or the number of steps to get there from the current position is less than what you've found so far (v[i+1], what you've found so far, > v[i] + 1, what you would get if you go from i). Does this it make it clearer?

Comment: I think so, let me try and debug your example and reference what you've pointed out here.

Comment: I'm getting an error:  ```if v[i + 1] == 0 or v[i + 1] > v[i] + 1: IndexError: list index out of range``` Can anyone help with this? I'm trying to understand the solution but no idea. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: @sarahkim You need to check that the destination is in bounds (`i+1 <= n` in this case). Always check you bounds unless you can prove that you're never going outside.

Comment: @Sorin Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

One more solution:

```
private static List<Integer> optimal_sequence(int n) {
    List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<>();

    int[] arr = new int[n + 1];

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + 1;
        if (i % 2 == 0) arr[i] = Math.min(1 + arr[i / 2], arr[i]);
        if (i % 3 == 0) arr[i] = Math.min(1 + arr[i / 3], arr[i]);

    }

    for (int i = n; i > 1; ) {
        sequence.add(i);
        if (arr[i - 1] == arr[i] - 1)
            i = i - 1;
        else if (i % 2 == 0 && (arr[i / 2] == arr[i] - 1))
            i = i / 2;
        else if (i % 3 == 0 && (arr[i / 3] == arr[i] - 1))
            i = i / 3;
    }
    sequence.add(1);

    Collections.reverse(sequence);
    return sequence;
}
```

Comment: can you explain the algorithm?

Comment: tho , this works for small numbers, for large numbers like 96234, it gives memory error.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     
while (n>0) {
    sequence.add(n);
        if (n % 3 == 0&&n % 2 == 0)
            n=n/3;
        else if(n%3==0)
            n=n/3;
        else if (n % 2 == 0&& n!=10)
            n=n/2;
        else
            n=n-1;
    }
Collections.reverse(sequence);
return sequence;
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my Dynamic programming (bottom-up & memoized)solution to the problem:

```
public class PrimitiveCalculator {

    1. public int minOperations(int n){
    2.    int[] M = new int[n+1];
    3.    M[1] = 0; M[2] = 1; M[3] = 1;
    4.    for(int i = 4; i <= n; i++){
    5.        M[i] = M[i-1] + 1;
    6.        M[i] = Math.min(M[i], (i %3 == 0 ? M[i/3] + 1 : (i%3 == 1 ? M[(i-1)/3] + 2 : M[(i-2)/3] + 3)));
    7.        M[i] = Math.min(M[i], i%2 == 0 ? M[i/2] + 1: M[(i-1)/2] + 2);
    8.    }
    9.    return M[n];
   10. }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new PrimitiveCalculator().minOperations(96234));
    }
}
```

Before going ahead with the explanation of the algorithm I would like to add a quick disclaimer:

> A DP solution is not reached at first attempt unless you have good
> experience solving lot of DP problems.

**Approach to solving through DP**

If you are not comfortable with DP problems then the best approach to solve the problem would be following:

1. Try to get a working brute-force recursive solution.
2. Once we have a recursive solution, we can look for ways to reduce the recursive step by adding memoization, where in we try remember the solution to the subproblems of smaller size already solved in a recursive step - This is generally a top-down solution.
3. After memoization, we try to flip the solution around and solve it bottom up (my Java solution above is a bottom-up one)
4. Once you have done above 3 steps, you have reached a DP solution.

**Now coming to the explanation of the solution above:**

Given a number '`n`' and given only 3 operations `{+1, x2, x3}`, the minimum number of operations needed to reach to '`n`' from `1` is given by recursive formula:

```
min_operations_to_reach(n) = Math.min(min_operations_to_reach(n-1), min_operations_to_reach(n/2), min_operations_to_reach(n/3))
```

If we flip up the memoization process and begin with number 1 itself then the above code starts to make better sense.
Starting of with trivial cases of 1, 2, 3
min_operations_to_reach(1) = 0 because we dont need to do any operation.
min_operations_to_reach(2) = 1 because we can either do (1 +1) or (1 x2), in either case number of operations is 1.
Similarly, min_operations_to_reach(3) = 1 because we can multiply 1 by 3 which is one operation.

Now taking any number x > 3, the min_operations_to_reach(x) is the minimum of following 3:

1. min_operations_to_reach(x-1) + 1 because whatever is the minimum operations to reach (x-1) we can add 1 to it to get the operation count to make it number x.
2. Or, if we consider making number x from 1 using multiplication by 3 then we have to consider following 3 options:

   - If x is divisible by 3 then min_operations_to_reach(x/3) + 1,
   - if x is not divisible by 3 then x%3 can be 1, in which case its min_operations_to_reach((x-1)/3) + 2, +2 because one operation is needed to multiply by 3 and another operation is needed to add 1 to make the number 'x'
   - Similarly if x%3 == 2, then the value will be min_operations_to_reach((x-2)/3) + 3. +3 because 1 operation to multiply by 3 and then add two 1s subsequently to make the number x.
3. Or,  if we consider making number x from 1 using multiplication by 2 then we have to consider following 2 options:

   - if x is divisible by 2 then its min_operations_to_reach(x/2) + 1
   - if x%2 == 1 then its min_operations_to_reach((x-1)/2) + 2.

Taking the minimum of above 3 we can get the minimum number of operations to reach x. Thats what is done in code above in lines 5, 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
def DPoptimal_sequence(n,operations):
    MinNumOperations=[0]
    l_no=[]
    l_no2=[]

    for i in range(1,n+1):
        MinNumOperations.append(None)
        for operation in operations:
            if operation==1:
                NumOperations=MinNumOperations[i-1]+1

            if operation==2 and i%2==0:
                NumOperations=MinNumOperations[int(i/2)]+1
            if  operation==3 and i%3==0:
                NumOperations=MinNumOperations[int(i/3)]+1
            if MinNumOperations[i]==None:
                MinNumOperations[i]=NumOperations
            elif NumOperations<MinNumOperations[i]:
                MinNumOperations[i]=NumOperations
        if MinNumOperations[i] ==  MinNumOperations[i-1]+1:
            l_no2.append((i,i-1))
        elif MinNumOperations[i] ==  MinNumOperations[int(i/2)]+1 and i%2 == 0:
            l_no2.append((i,int(i/2)))
        elif MinNumOperations[i] ==  MinNumOperations[int(i/3)]+1 and i%3 == 0:
            l_no2.append((i,int(i/3)))

        l_no.append((i,MinNumOperations[i]-1))
    #print(l_no)
    #print(l_no2)
    x=MinNumOperations[n]-1
    #print('x',x)
    l_no3=[n]
    while n>1:
        a,b = l_no2[n-1]
        #print(a,b)
        if b == a-1:
            n = n-1
            #print('1111111111111')
            #print('n',n)
            l_no3.append(n)
        elif b == int(a/2) and a%2==0:
            n = int(n/2)
            #print('22222222222222222')
            #print('n',n)
            l_no3.append(n)
        elif b == int(a/3) and a%3==0:
            n = int(n/3)
            #print('333333333333333')
            #print('n',n)
            l_no3.append(n)
    #print(l_no3)
    return x,l_no3
```

Comment: First i calculated the no of operations to reach the target no and then using that information calculated  the required sequence using dynamic approach.If  you need and explanation ask in the comments

Comment: Hi MOHAN and welcome to SO, why not simply you edit the question and put the descriptions and clarifications there? ... Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def optimal_sequence(n):
hop_count = [0] * (n + 1)

hop_count[1] = 1
for i in range(2, n + 1):
    indices = [i - 1]
    if i % 2 == 0:
        indices.append(i // 2)
    if i % 3 == 0:
        indices.append(i // 3)

    
    min_hops = min([hop_count[x] for x in indices])

    
    hop_count[i] = min_hops + 1


ptr = n
optimal_seq = [ptr]
while ptr != 1:

    
    candidates = [ptr - 1]
    if ptr % 2 == 0:
        candidates.append(ptr // 2)
    if ptr % 3 == 0:
        candidates.append(ptr // 3)

    
    ptr = min(
        [(c, hop_count[c]) for c in candidates],
        key=lambda x: x[1] 
    )[0]
    optimal_seq.append(ptr)

return reversed(optimal_seq)
```

Comment: Explanation:

First, we create a indexed 0 to n list, put all numbers as 0(hop_count), then we iterate from 2 to n, append the number(x)'s possible previous numbers(x-1,x//2,x//3) to a temporary list(indices), then we find the min(min_hop) number of optimal count of every number in the temporary list, the number with the least number of optimal count will be x's previous number, hence optimal number of count will be hop_count[min_hop] + 1.

Comment: Then, after we've gotten the list of optimal number of counts for every number to n, we will then create the optimal_seq list, first number will be n, then, create the second temporary list within the while loop(candidates), put in all the possible previous number starting with n(ptr), find the min of all the optimal number of count of these numbers, append the number that has the lowest number of count to the optimal seq list.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi fql! Your explanatory comments would be good to add to the main answer (through editing), so we have everything in one convenient place.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int count(int n, Map<Integer, Integer> lookup) {
        if(lookup.containsKey(n)) {
            return lookup.get(n);
        }
        
        if(n==1) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            int result;
            if(n%2==0 && n%3==0) {
                result =1+ 
                        //Math.min(count(n-1, lookup), 
                      Math.min(count(n/2, lookup), 
                            count(n/3, lookup));
            } else if(n%2==0) {
                result = 1+ Math.min(count(n-1, lookup), 
                                count(n/2, lookup));
            } else if(n%3==0) {
                result = 1+ Math.min(count(n-1, lookup), count(n/3, lookup));
            } else {
                result = 1+ count(n-1, lookup);
            }
            //System.out.println(result);
            lookup.put(n, result);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72319381/edit) to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).